# Usage of "call" when arranging a phone call

Tags: phrase-request

Imagine I'm one the phone with somebody and want to postpone the call. I know i can say

> I'll call you tomorrow

or

> Call me tomorrow

But what if I don't want to specify who is calling who? Can I use `"call"` too? Like

> Let's call tomorrow

What would be the common term to express something like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can say "Let's have a call tomorrow" or "Let's call each other tomorrow".

Note that "have a call" has a slight sense of this being a business call. If you want to be less formal, you might use "let's talk tomorrow" instead.

Answer (score 3):

Why would you EVER want to not specify who is making the call? If you don't specify, then in all likelihood, you are going to wait for them to call and they are going to wait for you to call, meaning the call will never happen. I suggest, instead, ask this;

> We should talk about this tomorrow, what would be a good time for me to call?

Comment: In German it is common to say it that way and we are still able to make that call happen ;-) Thought that there would be something similar in English.

Comment: @Lewis you might use this formulation if you want the other person to make the arrangements for the call, or if you call each other all the time as a matter of routine.

Comment: Perhaps it's obvious who'll initiate the call. For example, one of the parties may be able to make the call for free or one of the parties might be using an office phone system that only allows local numbers to be called.

Answer (score 1):

"Let's talk tomorrow" is fine in a context where it's obvious that the talking will be over the phone. For example, you're in Germany, I'm in the UK: if we agree to talk tomorrow, it's unlikely that either of us will travel however many hundred kilometres just to have that conversation.

Your suggestion of "let's call tomorrow" sounds a little unnatural to me but it would be understood perfectly.

Comment: Nice addition to Bigligs answer. My `"let's call tomorrow"` wasn't really a suggestion but a way of trying to make clear where I'm heading with my question ;-)